# Why is a penis an organ?

Tags: human-anatomy

According to Wikipedia an "An organ is a group of tissues with similar functions". I don't know anything about anatomy but it doesn't seem to me that a penis can be delimited somewhere to form a "group". Therefore  I do not understand why a penis is considered an organ.

Can you explain it to me ?

Comment: Organic = carbon based, thus teeth = organic

Comment: I though theeth were mineral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly, that's a terrible definition by Wikipedia.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/organ) defines an organ as:

> a differentiated structure (such as a heart, kidney, leaf, or stem) consisting of cells and tissues and performing some specific function in an organism

or

> bodily parts performing a function or cooperating in an activity

The important defining feature of an organ is not that the tissues *have similar functions* but that, together, the tissues comprise a functional whole that achieves some end goal.

For the penis, it consists of multiple tissues with different functions:

[image: Transverse penis section]

(from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK525966/figure/article-20668.image.f1/ - original from Gray's Anatomy)

The different tissues pictured here: the fibrous envelope, the corpora cavernosa, the septum pectiniforme, the urethra and blood vessels, the nervous tissue in the skin: all of these tissues have different individual functions: structural, erectile, carrying urine or semen, etc.

The key that unifies them into an organ is that the functions of the penis at the *organism* level (principally sexual function) are not served by any of these tissues alone, but rather by their combination in a full structure: an organ.

Ultimately, organ definitions are somewhat opinion-based: people are [lumpers and splitters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpers_and_splitters), so you might find conflicting definitions for which groupings of tissues reflect distinct organs, but I think by most standards you would find the penis to be considered a distinct organ, affiliated with but distinct from the primary sex organs and associated glands.